# Can i copy java tests to Katalon studio

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I have a large amount selenium tests written in java but im trying to switch over to Katalon studio to use the different features they provide. Im finding this very laborious, is there a way to just copy and past functions and methods over??

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way of bulk copying selenium tests. But tests written in Java and Selenium should work in Katalon. See also [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/using_selenium_webdriver_katalon_studio.html#how-katalon-studio-uses-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Could you please show some code example?

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655250/converting-a-java-code-containing-selenium-commands-to-groovy-in-order-to-be-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866879/how-to-execute-basic-java-code-in-katalon-studio), you can use in-built Eclipse-like editor in Katalon Studio.

Just switch to `</> Script` tab near the bottom of your work window, and paste Java code. No need for a main() method, since this is a Groovy editor and your code in the Test Case is basically a method (in a Groovy Script class).