# Converting a java code containing selenium commands to groovy in order to be inserted at script mode on Katalon

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I have a solution for a particular problem using Selenium Webdriver in Java environment, so the code in java and I want to put it in Katalon at script mode that runs groovy language and the code provided below contains selenium commands like findElements with. size() to count the elements in a panel which I did not find an equivalent for it in Katalon and also the code containing a casting from integer to string.

```
String changingselec = "";

int lastChildIndex = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div.panel")).size();

changingselec = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > app > div > manage-corr-app > div > div.flex-5.work-area-large > manage-user-recipient-groups > div > div.panel:nth-child(" + Integer.toString(lastChildIndex) + ")")).getText();

System.out.println(changingselec);
```

Comment: What error do you get just pasting that in?

Comment: First one regarding size,  Katakon throws No such property in testobject

Comment: In the code you gave, `size()` is a method call, not a property

Comment: @tim_yates I know, but the command driver. findElements takes. size() in selenium but in Katakon the command that does the same thing is findTestObject so this command does not take. size and throws error no such property which is size and here's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the Selenium commands you will need to switch driver, use this (for Chrome):

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
DriverFactory.changeWebDriver(driver)
// Continue with Selenium code...
```

Comment: Okay thank you Mate Mrše, it works with using WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver() only and then continued with selenium code, BUT the bizarre thing that size method gets 0 instead of the right size that is 10 or 11 for example. So it's very weird it runs well but with wrong size !!!!!!!!!!! Any suggestion please

Comment: What is the method are you talking about? And please upvote if you found the answer useful.

Comment: The method is .size() it returns 0 when running on Katalon despite it returns the correct value when running on "selenium WebDriver run by eclipse"

Comment: About using Java code in Katalon: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866879/how-to-execute-basic-java-code-in-katalon-studio.