# How to execute basic Java code in Katalon Studio

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I am trying to execute this basic program in Katalon Studio and Java but the O/P shows

```
if (i < 12)
```

Can you help me out on how to execute or use Java in Katalon Studio just like IntelliJ or Eclipse?

```
int i = 10;
if (i == 10) 
{ 
    // First if statement 
    if (i < 15) 
        System.out.println("i is smaller than 15"); 

    // Nested - if statement 
    // Will only be executed if statement above 
    // it is true 
    if (i < 12) 
        System.out.println("i is smaller than 12 too"); 
    else
        System.out.println("i is greater than 15"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

1. Open Katalon Studio
2. Add a new Test Case that you can call as you wish
3. Switch to `</> Script` tab near the bottom of your work window
4. Now you have an eclipse-like workspace, you just paste the above code (no need for main(), this is a Groovy editor)
5. Press the `Run` button at the top and you will get the following (or similar) output:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
2019-04-26 14:00:02.294 [34mINFO [0;39m [36mc.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   -[0;39m [39m--------------------[0;39m
2019-04-26 14:00:02.297 [34mINFO [0;39m [36mc.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   -[0;39m [39mSTART Test Cases/test so[0;39m
2019-04-26 14:00:02.864 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mtestcase.test so                         -[0;39m [39m1: i = 10[0;39m
2019-04-26 14:00:02.866 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mtestcase.test so                         -[0;39m [39m2: if (i == 10)[0;39m
2019-04-26 14:00:02.868 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mtestcase.test so                         -[0;39m [39m1: if (i < 15)[0;39m
i is smaller than 15
2019-04-26 14:00:02.883 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36mtestcase.test so                         -[0;39m [39m2: if (i < 12)[0;39m
i is smaller than 12 too
2019-04-26 14:00:02.886 [34mINFO [0;39m [36mc.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   -[0;39m [39mEND Test Cases/test so
```

**Note:** In Katalon Studio, you have to import Java libraries manually. This tool is not able to import automatically as eclipse can.
For example, if you have to format data then need to import the libraries below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.UUID;

 public class TestData {
 private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new 
 SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
 public static String getTimeStamp() {
    Timestamp tm = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String timestamp=sdf.format(tm);
    return timestamp;
    }
 }
```

Comment: As you mentioned _...this is a Groovy editor..._ does the question have anything to do with [tag:groovy] to be tagged?

Comment: Nopes, [tag:groovy] tag was added by OP. I have removed [tag:selenium] but am not sure about [tag:groovy]

Comment: The O/P for me shows me like                                                                             04-26-2019 09:10:37 PM if (i < 12)
Elapsed time: